# How to create a dedicated side bar menu in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am really new to Bootstrap and have been fooling around with it. I want to make something like the following:

> Main menu
>
> side bar | content
>
> side bar | other content

What I have done so far was to make `span4` class in each row for the side bar, but is there a way to dedicate that side of the page to the side menu and have the other side for content, etc?

EDIT: I am using Bootstrap 2.3.2., not the new 3.0 RC.

Comment: which bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: 2.3.2 the latest stable version i believe.

Comment: I'd create one parent row and have two spans in it, one for each column. Everything else happens inside those two spans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean as in the example here: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/fluid.html - if so, the markup for the body is:

```
 <body>

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <p class="navbar-text pull-right">
          Logged in as <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Username</a>
        </p>
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span3">
      <div class="well sidebar-nav">
        <ul class="nav nav-list">
          <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li class="nav-header">Sidebar</li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.well -->
    </div><!--/span-->
    <div class="span9">
      <div class="hero-unit">
        <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called the hero unit and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="span4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="span4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
      </div><!--/row-->
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="span4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
        <div class="span4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div><!--/span-->
      </div><!--/row-->
    </div><!--/span-->
  </div><!--/row-->

  <hr>

  <footer>
    <p>&copy; Company 2013</p>
  </footer>

</div><!--/.fluid-container-->
```

Thanks, Mark

Comment: Oh, thanks! i looked over the examples and missed it i think.